# Php APNS Best Practice

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I wonder if there are some "ready to use" solutions for the server-side of the apple push notification service out there. I was browsing the web for two days now to get an overview what exists, what can be used for new projects.

I found up till now:

EasyApns ( http://www.easyapns.com )

Looks very easy to install an run, no need for changes at the php distribution and no special requirements to the server.

PhpAPNs ( http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/ )

A bit more complicated, the php needs posix support and also shared memory buildt in.

Are there others out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [PHP-Mysql](https://github.com/bortuzar/PHP-Mysql---Apple-Push-Notification-Server) for registering and pushing to devices. You may have a look at it. It's easy to understand.

PHPApns can be used without shared memory id you only use Push and feedback. Those requirements are needed for the server-push part.

Comment: What means "server push part" in Detail? For sending notifications to specific devices and catching the feedback this is not needed?

Comment: @Murdock
I checked out the PHP-Mysql code that you posted and it works great using a development certificate, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work with a production certificate. Could you help?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the following apns-based application here

http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

You can download PushChatServer application. For push notiication part check out push folder.